# Run two main class instances from one project in InteliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, development-environment

Hello I have a problem that I want to run two distinct instances in one project. One is in Receiver module and second one in Sender. When I try to select Main class for another module in Run/Debug application I get following error. Is it even possible to run like this in idea ? I know this worked in Visual studio when we created new sollution.  How about here ? [image]

Comment: Intellij definitely supports running multiple classes from the same project.

Comment: From the picture it doesn't look like your `Recv` class has a correct `main` method. As you can see on the icons there is no green play icon `>` overlay like there is on the `Send` class icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your `main` method has `String[] args`?

Remember that a class to be executable must have the following method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

}
```

the throwing part is optional

Comment: Such fail... That was it.